# How to forward all requests to .net core app from nginx

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I've deployed my .net core web application to Ubuntu 16.04 server with nginx and I want to send all incoming requests to my .net core application. I used tutorial from here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1). My sites-available/default file

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com *.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;   
}
```

Everything works fine except of one action when I want to pass parameters to change my image size on the fly

```
http://example.com/api/files/get/5beffcb65a8e8f1c700a1a22/image?w=400&h=400
```

In that case I receive 404 error. That error returned by Nginx. I tested it locally by curl and perform direct request to my .net core app and it works ok.

So how to configure nginx to send all requests with all parameters as is to my .net core applicatoin?

Comment: I diged dipper and found the in system log there are some erros such as the type initializer for 'gdip' threw an exception I think that is the problem. Could anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set proxy-redirect to off.  Refer to this link for an explanation:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290141/nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection